# C# reflection getting nullable type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, fieldtype

i have class, with fields of double? type.
with reflection i get fields

```
Parameters cl = new Parameters();
FieldInfo[] fi = cl.GetType().GetFields((BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance));
```

now, i want get fields, only with double? type, gow can i get this type, to compare with fields from fi?

smth like:

```
if(fi[0].FieldType == (double?).GetType()){...}
```

Comment: you have asked 9 questions already and never accepted an answer as solution.

Comment: Your question is pretty weak. Try to be more clear please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(fi[0].FieldType == typeof(Nullable<double>)){...}
```

or

```
if(fi[0].FieldType == typeof(double?)){...}
```

Comment: ...or just `typeof(double?)` to keep the used type identifiers consistent (even though it is equivalent).